# R data frame create a new variable which corresponds to one of the existing one

Tags: r, data-cleaning, data-formats

[image]

Currently this is what I get. "community_area_clean" is the new variable that I added by extracting a variable that lists all the communities from a data frame. "CommArea_Name" is the original "unclean" variable. But I find that the names in "community_area_clean" do not correspond to the names in "CommArea_Name". How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Does that `CommArea_Num` column mean anything? It looks like LINCOLN SQUARE has a 4 there and is the fourth in the community_area_clean column.  Same for ROGERS PARK, which has a 1 and is first in the other column. Is that true all the way through? Does the AREA_KM correspond to the CommArea_Name place or the community_area_clean place in each row/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my assumptions about `CommArea_Num` are correct, then:

```
data$community_area_clean = data$community_area_clean[data$CommAreaNum]
```

should remap that column. Note that the `AREA_KM` fields will remain in the order currently shown.

Comment: Oh yes! I think you are right! But how can I change the order of AREA_KM so that it corresponds to other variables?

Comment: Do the same thing with `AREA_KM` instead. Note you should end up with the area of ROGERS PARK as 2.700750 units. If this is actually the area of KENWOOD then some more fiddling required...